# How can i exclude ".exe" file types from my git commit?

Tags: git, gitignore

I can exclude single files from my git commit but I want to exclude all files which have `.exe` file type.

Comment: add `**/*.exe` in `.gitignore`.

Comment: Why was this question tagged as `C++`?

Comment: google: `.gitignore c++ <your platform>` there are examples of standard content of this file. Just copy some to cover more cases. Good practice is not to use `git commit -a` just add files to index manually `git add <pattern>` to have control what is tracked by git.

Comment: @LeiYang `*.exe` is enough. The patterns are recursive by default.

Comment: @Biffen, For me it is not sufficient. Probably it depends on git client version. I have 2.17.1.

Answer (score 4):

you can use regex as a pattern in the git ignore file as bellow:

```
# Ignore all
*

# Unignore all with extensions
!*.*

# Unignore all dirs
!*/

### Above combination will ignore all files without extension ###

# Ignore files with extension `.class` & `.exe`
*.class
*.exe

# Ignore `bin` dir
bin/
# or
*/bin/*

# Unignore all `.exe` in `bin` dir
!*/bin/*.exe
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Technically these are [glob patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), not [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Regular expressions are more general than globs: a glob expression can be converted to a regular expression, but not vice versa (in general of course: a specific regex that results from converting a glob can be converted back to the corresponding glob). Git uses globs here because they are much simpler to get right, and hence do the desired job.